# Exclude beforeShowDay when determining minDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using beforeShowDay to exclude holidays and weekends, however I want the beforeShowDays to be excluded when calculating the minDate.

E.g. if the current day of the week is friday and the minDate is 2, I want the weekend to be excluded from the equation. So instead of monday being the first date you can select, I want it to be wednesday.

This is my jQuery:

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({
minDate: 2, maxDate: "+12M", // Date range
beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates
});
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
function includeDate(date) {
    return date.getDay() !== 6 && date.getDay() !== 0;
}

function getTomorrow(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1);
}

$("#date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [includeDate(date)];
    },
    minDate: (function(min) {
        var today = new Date();
        var nextAvailable = getTomorrow(today);
        var count = 0;
        var newMin = 0; // Modified 'min' value

        while(count < min) {
            if (includeDate(nextAvailable)) {
                count++;
            }
            newMin++; // Increase the new minimum
            nextAvailable = getTomorrow(nextAvailable);            
        }
        return newMin;
    })(2) // Supply with the default minimum value.
});
```

Basically, figure out where the next valid date is, leveraging the method you've already defined for `beforeShowDay`. If my logic is correct (and you're only excluding weekends), this value can only be either 2 or 4: 2 If there are weekends in the way (Thurs. or Friday) and 2 if not.

It gets more complicated if you have other days you're excluding, but I think the logic still follows.

Here's the code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TpSLC/